# C# Windows Forms Export to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have a simple application.
My application loads a csv, alter some data and exports to excel.

[image: Application]

When I click "Exportar..." it exports.
The code is following.

```
    private void cmdExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdExport.Enabled = false;
        cmdSelecionar.Enabled = false;

        //Copy DataGridView to clipboard
        dgvMain.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
        dgvMain.MultiSelect = true;
        dgvMain.SelectAll();

        DataObject dataObj = dgvMain.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);

        //Open an excel instance and paste the copied data
        Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);

        cmdSelecionar.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Problem:
When I export, it adds a blank column in the begining, the "A" column.
Why this is happening? 
Whats wrong with my code?

The excel print follows:

[image: Excel exported]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have row headers on your DataGridView, you can see it in your image as the light blue highlighted column with the `>` arrow at the top.

If you don't need them you can disable them with `dgvMain.RowHeadersVisible = false;`

Alternatively you could delete the first column after pasting:

```
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
range.EntireColumn.Delete(Missing.Value);
```

Comment: dgvMain.RowHeadersVisible = false; solved the problem.
Thank you @Equalsk

Answer (score 0):

You are pasting from the clipboard which is fine, but I suspect your data in the clipboard contains a blank column.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the following works:

```
Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[A1, 1];
Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[0, 1];
```